# Из чего складывается суммарный объём занимаемой сайтом памяти?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, оптимизация-сайтов

Если говорить о серьёзном сайтостроении, то типовая папка с проектом будет иметь примерно такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поясняю для новичков в веб-разработке, кто читает этот вопрос:

- **app** - здесь файлы для разработки. Не все они понадобятся для готового сайта.
- **css** - стилевые файлы. На этапе разработки допускается большое количество этих файлов.
- **fonts** - шрифты
- **img** - изображения
- **js** - файлы с JavaScript-скриптами.
- **sass** - файлы css-препроцессора `SASS`
- **dist** - папка сайтом, подготовленном для размещения. Благодаря GULP, возможно объединение всех CSS файлов в один, тоже и с JS. SASS-папа для готового сайта не нужна.

Вопрос: какие файлы определяют суммарный объём занимаемой сайтом памяти?
Очевидно, это будут HTML или PHP-файлы, CSS-файл (благодаря GULP - один), JS-файл. Что ещё? Изображения? Базы данных?

Comment: Вы же понимаете что в `app/img/` может быть 1b и 13Mb. Плюс - неясно что Вы имеете ввиду под памятью в данном случае.

Comment: Меня интересует тот объём занимаемой памяти 1) который имеет влияние на быстродействие сайта 2) который видит поисковый робот, когда заходит на сайт, и даёт оценку по данному параметру. Во втором случае из-за корпоративной мы не знаем, как работает робот, но есть много статей с результатами экспериментов, а также выступления представителей Google - может кто-нибудь читал статьи по этому поводу.

Comment: Интересно, как вы из PHP-файлов и баз данных собрались вес сайта высчитывать. А вообще, как любой нормальный человек скомпилируйте всё что можно, минифицируйте, вылижите и удалите весь лишний код, а затем прогоняйте страницы сайта, скажем, через [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) - он вам и вес подскажет, и на косяки укажет. Очевидно, что на вес будет влиять всё, к чему подключается пользователь: стили, скрипты, аяксы, шрифты, картинки, даже манифесты.

Comment: @terron Ну вот например `jQuery` рекомендуется подключать с внешних источников ([cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/#), к примеру) в целях оптимизации. Если всё так, как Вы сказали, то казалось бы, какая разница - что jQuey на Вашем хостинге, что на cdnjs - пользователь к ней и так и так подключается, и это увеличивает вес сайта.

Comment: jQuery рекомендуется подключать с внешних источников потому, что скрипты с cdn часто уже есть в кеше браузера посетителя (потому что вероятно он посещал другой сайт на котором jQuery с того же cnd), и поэтому скрипт не скачивается с cdn, а берется из кеша. Это уменьшает время загрузки сайта и трафик. Что за мифологический вес сайта вас волнует мне вообще не понятно.

Comment: Тогда начну с цели. Я стремлюсь к тому, чтобы поисковик поставил хорошую оценку по критерию "размер сайта" (а что для поисковик понимает под "размером", можно узнать только из статей и интервью разработчиков) . Понятно, что нужно минифицировать css и js, оптимизировать png и т. д. Но помимо этого есть ещё базы данных, файлы (хотя и большинство, не все данные удобно хранить в БД), админ-панель и т. д. Задача обсуждения - узнать, насколько об этом доступная информация, что поисковик принимает во внимание при оценке занимаемого сайтом объёма памяти, а что - нет.

Comment: @Gurebu Bokofu, насколько я понял, вы переживаете за вес исходников сайта. Ответ очевиден: поисковик **никак** не сможет узнать реальный вес исходников и базы данных сайта, потому что эта информация доступна только команде разработчиков ресурса. Важны только скорость отклика сервера, скорость генерации страницы, вес отдаваемого HTML, ассетов и, возможно, оптимизация, чтобы стили и скрипты не жрали всю оперативную память пользователя. Короче всё то, что можно получить через вкладку Network отладчика Хрома. Каким образом вы дошли до этого вопроса - мне неясно.